# How to fill a form with a button click?

Tags: angular, forms

I want to fill a form by clicking a button.
I cant figure out how to access/fill the values with a angular function.

I have inputs like this with different names and different ngmodels:

```
<input type="text" name="id" [(ngModel)]="id" placeholder="id">
```

and my button is:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary-sm submit-button" type="button" 
(click)="fillForm()">
  Auto Fill
</button>
```

How can i set those values from within the fillForm() function?

Comment: what version of angular? did you try something like: fillForm(){ this.id=1; this.exampleInputValue = "example value"; //etc }

Comment: how stupid of me, thats exactly what i was looking for! thanks sarah

Comment: no problem at all. :) glad to help :)